# string manipulation to return string value in php?

Tags: php

How can I convert a PHP string from "-----071-3234443-----“ to "071-3234443"?

This string should contain a telephone number. But it contains leading and tailoring dashes?

Comment: use [trim](http://php.net/trim) function

Comment: `trim()` function will work great for your case. https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/trim.php

Answer (score 3):

You can use the trim function:

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

```php
$tel = trim($tel, "-");
```